# Leap year and aggregations per week in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm doing a nested aggregation, per year, and then per week each year in elasticsearch. Leap years have 53 weeks, but the result from ElasticSearch gives the last week of a leap year key="1" and not "53". How can I make ElasticSearch return 53 in stead of 1 for the last week?

Here is my query:

```
GET _search
    {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "activities_per_year": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "start",
        "interval": "1y",
        "format": "yyyy"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "activities_per_week": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "start",
            "interval": "week",
            "format": "w"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result (removed data in the middle):

```
"key_as_string": "2008",
           "key": 1199145600000,
           "doc_count": 872,
           "activities_per_week": {
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key_as_string": "1",
                    "key": 1199059200000,
                    "doc_count": 6
                 },
                 {
                    "key_as_string": "2",
                    "key": 1199664000000,
                    "doc_count": 5
                 },
                 {
                    "key_as_string": "3",
                    "key": 1200268800000,
                    "doc_count": 15
                 },       {
                    "key_as_string": "51",
                    "key": 1229299200000,
                    "doc_count": 18
                 },
                 {
                    "key_as_string": "52",
                    "key": 1229904000000,
                    "doc_count": 7
                 },
                 {
                    "key_as_string": "1",
                    "key": 1230508800000,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
```

2008 is a leap year, and the last week has "key_as_string": "1". I want this to be 53, so I can add it to my dictionary :) How can I do this?

Also, elasticsearch returns two weeks with "key_as_string": "1" for year 2013, and I don't think 2013 is a leap year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has some subtle gotchas that one needs to be aware of. First of all, Elasticsearch uses [Joda Time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for date-time related stuff.

Secondly, take a look at [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/field.html#weekyear) explanation of what actually is a "week":

> A week based year is one where dates are expressed as a day of week,
>   week number and year (week based). The following description is of the
>   ISO8601 standard used by implementations of this method in this
>   library.
>
> Weeks run from 1 to 52-53 in a week based year. The first day of the
>   week is defined as Monday and given the value 1.
>
> The first week of a year is defined as the first week that has at
>   least four days in the year. As a result of this definition, week 1
>   may extend into the previous year, and week 52/53 may extend into the
>   following year. Hence the need for the year of weekyear field.
>
> For example, 2003-01-01 was a Wednesday. This means that five days,
>   Wednesday to Sunday, of that week are in 2003. Thus the whole week is
>   considered to be the first week of 2003. Since all weeks start on
>   Monday, the first week of 2003 started on 2002-12-30, ie. in 2002.
>
> The week based year has a specific text format. 2002-12-30 (Monday
>   30th December 2002) would be represented as 2003-W01-1. 2003-01-01
>   (Wednesday 1st January 2003) would be represented as 2003-W01-3.

So, in your case, you are seeing 29-12-2008 as belonging to week 1, because Dec 29th 2008 is in a week with three days in 2008 and four days in 2009. According to the above rule, that's week #1 from year 2009. And this has nothing to do with leap years. To give you an example, try indexing 31-12-2009 and 31-12-2015. Both will give you week 53 and they are not leap years.

To see these things better I suggest the following format for your aggregation: `"format": "x-w---yyyy-MM-dd"`:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "activities_per_year": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "start",
        "interval": "1y",
        "format": "yyyy"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "activities_per_week": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "start",
            "interval": "week",
            "format": "x-w---yyyy-MM-dd"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent explanation :-) 
But why doesn't Elasticsearch "filter out" dates from 2009 when my first aggregation has interval: 1y? I thought my sub-aggregation "activities_per_week" got it's input from documents matching the "activities_per_year"-aggregation?