# How do I fix elasticsearch returning "2014-01" for date "2014-12-31" with format "yyyy-ww"

Tags: elasticsearch

For the date "2014-12-31", the elasticsearch 2.4 will return "2014-01" with format "yyyy-ww", actually I expect it return "2015-01"

I am using such query:

```
{
  "_source": [ "9303" ],
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "9303": {
              "from": 2014-12-31",
              "to": "2014-12-31"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "explain": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "9303": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "9303",
        "interval": "week",
        "format": "yyyy-ww",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Shanghai"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format `x-ww`. I found the answer here: [Leap year and aggregations per week in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671300/leap-year-and-aggregations-per-week-in-elasticsearch) -- which explains in detail how it works. Ultimately the `key` returned is the unix timestamp of the beginning of the week (which is in 2014), and the `key_as_string` is exactly that timestamp formatted according to your format. `yyyy` means the exact year of that timestamp, and `x` is the "weekyear". ([joda time docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html))

Comment: Yes, you are right.
It could use "x" as the "weekyear", from the format refrerence https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html#date-format-pattern